# LocalStorage with click event

Tags: javascript

In a personnal project, i create a button that change the color of another one on click.

```
<body>
<style>
    .enable{
        background: #F75611 !important;
        pointer-events: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .disable{
        background: grey !important;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

</style>
<button type="button" id="Act1" class="enable">test1</button>
<button type="button" id="Act2" class="disable">test2</button>

</body>


var act1 = document.getElementById('Act1')
var act2 = document.getElementById('Act2')


act1.addEventListener('click', function(){
   act2.classList.remove("disable")
   act2.classList.add("enable")
})
```

Now i would like to store the active class of a button, because when i reload the state of the button reset.
I tried to adapt and learn with other ask in this forum but i don't really how to adapt this storage to my code.
If someone could help me with this, it's gonna be very cool.

Thanks

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store the state of the second button.

```js
var act1 = document.getElementById('Act1')
var act2 = document.getElementById('Act2')
function act1Clicked(){
   act2.classList.remove("disable");
   act2.classList.add("enable");
   localStorage.setItem('btn2-enabled', true);
}
if (localStorage.getItem('btn2-enabled'))
    act1Clicked();
act1.addEventListener('click', act1Clicked);
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tj9efd2x/)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is the object through which you can access the localStorage.

> localStorage.setItem(itemName, "itemValue") is used to set the item.

> let item = localStorage.getItem(itemName) is used to get the item.

In your case, you can store the **button id** and **className** of the active button using the **setItem** Function.
This way you will know the **id of the button and the respective className** too.
Simply just assign the values to the respective elements.

**I did not clearly understand you. And I cannot comment cause of reputation otherwise would have asked in the comments.**

Answer (score 0):

To use the `localStorage` there is two methods : one to read into it and another one to write data in it.

You can use it this way :

- `localStorage.getItem(the_item_you_stored)`, to read a value stored previously in the `localStorage`. Return null if it does not exist.
- `localStorage.setItem(the_item_you_want_to_store, the_value_of_the_item_you_want_to_store)`, to write a value into the `localStorage`.

I wrote the code based on your question below :

```js
// We check if the localStorage already have something loaded
const classAct2 = localStorage.getItem('act2') ?? "enable";

// We remove the class to prepare for the new one
document.getElementById('Act2').removeAttribute('class');

// We add either the class in the localStorage or by default the enable class
document.getElementById('Act2').classList.add(classAct2);

// You should use let instead of var
let act1 = document.getElementById('Act1')
let act2 = document.getElementById('Act2')

act1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    act2.classList.remove("disable");
    act2.classList.add("enable");

    // We set the localStorage to the class of the button with the value we want
    localStorage.setItem('act2', 'enable');
});
```